# Не выводится правильный ответ

Tags: c#, математика, ряды

Вычислить с точностью E=10<sup>-10</sup> значение,где 1/(1+x) ~ 1-x+x<sup>2</sup>-x<sup>3</sup>+...+(-1)<sup>n-1</sup>*x<sup>n</sup>

Как преобразовать формулу?
Пример:
при 1/(1+x) , x-любое число . Если к примеру я возьму 12, то 1/(1+12) Ответ должен быть 0,0769230769230769‬.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double e = Math.Pow(10, -10);
    int x = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(func(x, e));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public static double func(int x, double e)
{
    double m2, m1,sum=0;

    m1 = 1 - x + Math.Pow(x, 2) - Math.Pow(x, 3);
    sum = m1;

    while (m1>e)
    {
        n++;
        m2= Math.Pow(-1,x-1) * Math.Pow(x, x);
        sum = sum + m2;
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

Comment: У вас цикл бесконечен т.к. условие `m1 > e` не изменяется от итерации к итерации.

Comment: Этот ряд точно сходится для |x| >= 1? По коду - у вас явно не то в степень возводится в `Math.Pow(n, n)`. И, наверное, вам хватило бы одного значения m - т.к. именно его вы должны сравнивать с e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для какого такого **целого** n вы пытаетесь считать? При сходимости ряда в (-1,1)?

Должно быть что-то вроде (я на C# не программирую, могу в языке нахомутать):

```
public static double func(double x, double e)
{
    if (x*x >= 1) return 0; // Как показатель ошибки

    double sum = 1, term = 1;

    for(int k = 1; term*term > e*e; ++k)
    {
        term = - term * x;
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

Comment: при 1/(1+x) , x-любое число . Если к примеру я возьму 12, то 1/(1+12) Ответ должен быть 0,0769230769230769‬

Comment: Учите матчасть, как говорится. Математику. Ряды. Сходимость. Не выйдет :) Для простоты подставим 2. Имеем: 1-2+4-8+12-... - с какого перепугу это равно 0.33333333...? Не пишите глупостей, не позорьтесь... Кстати, ряд у вас записан неверно - это ряд для 1/(1+x)...

Comment: Я и поэтому суда и обратилась за помощью, я тоже не поняла как из целых в дробное получатся. Так было дано и не я придумывала это задание. Я придерживаюсь мнении если что-то не получается ищи ошибки в коде и логике. Было бы все логично, все сделала бы сама. Мне было интересно, как формулу преобразовать.

Comment: В "дано" явно либо было указано для x от -1 до 1, либо не было сказано вообще ничего. Особенно если была приведена эта формула :) Приведите **полный и точный** текст задания, посмотрим...

Comment: [Harry] Точнее задачу описать не смогу. Спасибо за ваши усилия)

Comment: Да просто дайте то, что задал преподаватель. Но **дословно**.